# How to print filename/current directory as a title in octave plot from bash?

Tags: bash, plot, octave

I am new to octave and need to plot a 2-D graph with customized title either as a file name or current directory name. I tried passing pwd in the plot.m file but it gives me a complete path instead of directory name only. Actually all I need is a customized title without manually hard coding the string inside xlabel('strings').

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Octave but this works on MATLAB:

```
current_directory_name = pwd;
current_directory_split = regexp(current_directory_name,'/','split');
string_of_interest = current_directory_split(end);
xlabel(string_of_interest);
```

I am assuming you are on *NIX computer. For Windows computer, change `/` to `\` in the split command.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a portable way of retrieving the file name w/o the directory name. Use `fileparts()`:

```
[dir, name, ext, ver] = fileparts(pwd)
```

If you later decide to join strings, use `filesep` which is portable no matter if you're on Unix or not.